# How to change the size of an existing scene2d.ui widget in a window/table?

Tags: libgdx

I'm attempting to resize a scene2d.ui window (which is basically a table that can be moved around) and its contents. So far I can only successfully change the window size itself, but not its contents. I'm doing it like this:

```
window.setWidth(newTableWidth);
textField.setWidth(newFieldWidth);
window.invalidate(); <--- New size of window is drawn properly when invalidate() is called
textField.invalidate(); <--- New textField size is NOT drawn, however
```

In this case, the window contains a text field which I'm trying to resize along with the window, but only the window gets redrawn with its new size while the text field remains the same.

How do I properly update the widgets within the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on BeenX's answer, it's evident that the size is set on the cell of the table that contains the widget, rather than on the widget itself. The `table.add()` method returns a cell, so when running `table.add(textField).width(600).height(60)` the width and height is being applied to this cell.

Hence my solution to update an already existing cell was to find the cell I want to update with `table.getCells()` then apply the new width on that. The example below changes the width of the last cell in the list.

```
List<Cell> cells = window.getCells(); 
Cell cell = cells.get(cells.size()-1);
cell.width(newWidth);
```

Answer (score 16):

I had the same Problem and it took a while to get the solution.
Take a look at this quastion [slider always has default width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910879/slider-always-has-default-width).

The solution is:

> UI widgets do not set their own size and position. Instead, the parent widget sets the size and position of each child. Widgets provide a minimum, preferred, and maximum size that the parent can use as hints. Some parent widgets, such as Table, can be given constraints on how to size and position the children. To give a widget a specific size in a layout, the widget's minimum, preferred, and maximum size are left alone and size constraints are set in the parent. 
>   [Layout at Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2dui#Layout)

From the wiki of libGDX. They just added it. So while you add those widgets to the table just add the line `.width(newTableWidth)` at the end and it should be at the right width.

```
table.add(textField).width(600).height(60);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is how I do set the size of the widget initially, but I'm trying to change it after it has been set. I'm resizing the table, but everything within keeps the same size until I add a new row. Do you know if it's possible to "refresh" the widget's sizes without adding something new to the table? So far this seems like a weakness with scene2d to me, it doesn't seem like it's designed to be dynamically changed after it's been set up once.

Comment: you do resize the cell of it not the widget itself. after that you  do use the invalidate on the table. i think its not weak its just how it works

Comment: Yes I just realized now as well that the changes need to be done to cell, not the widget. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: your wellcome. It took me like 5-6 Days to find out because there were nothing written about it. I made a ticket at that time to get the information about it.