# Need an analog for "inline block" from CSS in scene2d.ui

Tags: libgdx

Is there a way to create a widget like Morrowind's items list using scene2d.ui? That is, a container where you can put fixed-sized elements and they would stack up in a row (or in a column) until they fill the parent container by width/height, so after that they'd stack up in the next row/column?

[image]

In the image you can see scrolling, but I'd still accept an answer that doesn't allow scrolling. Also I'm aware that inline block elements in CSS don't stack vertically (like they do in Morrowind), that's just the closest analogy I can come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a set of HorizontalFlowGroup and VerticalFlowGroup widgets to perform that type of layout.

Here's the source of them:
https://github.com/MobiDevelop/maps-editor/blob/master/maps-editor/src/com/mobidevelop/maps/editor/ui/

If you put the HorizontalFlowGroup in a ScrollPane with vertical scroll, it will fill the width then move to the next row, allowing vertical scrolling. If you put a VerticalFlowGroup in a ScrollPane with horizontal scrolling, it will fill the height and move to the next column, allowing for horizontal scrolling. In either case, if you use a uniform size for the child widgets, they will all align as a grid.

Comment: Works fine, many thanks! Sorry for not accepting the answer for some time: I just didn't have time to check if the code actually works.