# Stop the libgdx TextButton from changing size depending on text

Tags: java, user-interface, size, libgdx, scene2d

I am using a textbutton that changes its text from OFF to ON when you click on it. But once it does that the size is completely different. Is there a way to make the button keep its current size? I've tried setScale and setSize of the button but it does not seem to do anything. I am using the button in a table if that is relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the table, you should change the size of the `cell` instead.

For example, lets imagine that your code was:

```
TextButton btn = new TextButton(...);
btn.setSize(100, 100);
table.add(btn);
```

You should define it like this instead:

```
TextButton btn = new TextButton(...);
table.add(btn).size(100, 100); // <-- resize cell, not button
```

Please refer [this](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout) document for more information.

Comment: Wow..it was that simple? Now I feel silly xD. But thanks! Appreciate it!

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910879/slider-always-has-default-width/16021254#16021254 .